# Is there a way to create a normal list in R when adding elements in for loop or splitting string? 'not a list of list'

Tags: r, list

Is there a way to create a normal list? Not 'list of list'. I am having to unlist my list.

```
prior_trt = "chemo or egfr"

if (str_detect(tolower(prior_trt), "or")){
     prior_trt = str_split(prior_trt, " or ")
 }

> prior_trt
[[1]]
[1] "chemo" "egfr" 

unlist(prior_trt)
```

Similar situation

```
prior_trt = c("chemo","egfr")
for (i in 1:length(prior_trt)) {
     pt[[i]] <- paste0("prior_trt_", tolower(prior_trt[i]))
}

> pt
[[1]]
[1] "prior_trt_chemo"

[[2]]
[1] "prior_trt_egfr"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `str_split` returns a list. You can return a matrix by using the argument `simplify=TRUE` (see [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_split))

For your second case, you can define `pt` as a vector and fill it (using single brackets)

```r
library(stringr)
prior_trt = c("chemo","egfr")
pt <- rep(NA, length(prior_trt))
for (i in 1:length(prior_trt)) {
     pt[i] <- paste0("prior_trt_", tolower(prior_trt[i]))
}
```